# Why is my h2 database inserting a row with default values on each spring boot restart

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, h2

My h2 database creates a row with default values each time I restart my spring boot application. This is happening for my users entity.

```java
@Component
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity(name = "Users")
@Table(name = "Users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="userId")
    private int id;
    @Column(unique=true)
    private String username = "";
    private String city = "";
    private String state = "";
    private String zip = "";
    private boolean peanutAll = false;
    private boolean eggAll = false;
    private boolean dairyAll = false;
}
```

Here is my properties file

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:dcbapp;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false;
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

I'm not sure if my controller and service class will be helpful or not since I'm not making a request but I'll still provide it just incase.

```java
@RestController

@RequestMapping(path="/user")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired UserService userv;
    @Autowired User returnUser;
    
    @PostMapping("/add")
    public ResponseEntity<User> addUser(@Valid @RequestBody User user){
    Optional<User> tempUser =   Optional.ofNullable(userv.addUser(user));
    return ResponseEntity.of(tempUser);

    }
    
    @PutMapping("/update")
    public ResponseEntity<User> updateUser(@Valid @RequestBody User user){
        User tempUser = userv.updateUser(user);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(tempUser);
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/{username}")
    public ResponseEntity<User> getUser(@PathVariable(value="username") String username ){
        User tempUser = userv.getUserByUsername(username);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(tempUser);
    }
}
```

```java
@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired UserRepo userRepo;
    @Autowired User tempUser;
    @Autowired 
    
    public User addUser(User user) {
        if(userRepo.existsById(user.getId())) {
            throw new UserAlreadyExistsException(String.format("User %s already exists", user.getUsername()));
        }

        else {
                return userRepo.save(user);
            }       
        }
    
    public User getUserByUsername(String username) {        
        User tempUser = userRepo.findByUsername(username).orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException(String.format("User doesn't exist: %s", username)));      
        return tempUser;
    }
    
    public User getUserById(int id) {
        User tempUser = userRepo.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException(String.format("User doesn't exist with id: %d", id)));
        return tempUser;
    }
    
    //you need to include id in json body request
    public User updateUser(User user) throws UserNotFoundException, ChangeUsernameException, MustMakeChangeException{
        Optional<User> tempUser1 = userRepo.findById(user.getId());
        if(tempUser1.isEmpty()) {
            throw new UserNotFoundException(String.format("User doesn't exist: %s", user.getUsername()));
        }
        User tempUser = tempUser1.get();
        
        if(!tempUser.getUsername().equals(user.getUsername())) {
            throw new ChangeUsernameException(String.format("Unable to change username: %s", user.getUsername()));
        }
        else if(tempUser.getCity().equals(user.getCity()) && tempUser.getState().equals(user.getState()) && tempUser.getZip().equals(user.getZip())) {
            
            throw new MustMakeChangeException("You must make an update to user");
        }
        else {
            
            return userRepo.save(user);
        }
    
    }
}
```

Comment: If you log a stack trace from the `User` constructors, what is creating an instance?

Comment: Remove the @Component annotation from the entity class. This is the cause. Spring creates an instance on start up.

Comment: Why is your use an `@Component` that shouldn't be the case, remove it as a field from your service and controller as well? Next to that don't use `@Data` with entities see https://deinum.biz/2019-02-13-Lombok-Data-Ojects-Arent-Entities/

Comment: I need to have the component annotations there so spring can auto detect beans. I also have a component annotation on two other entity classes and they're not creating a default row so I don't think my @Component is the cause

Comment: I figured it out. I had an empty @Autowire annotation

Comment: You definitely don't need to make a Spring bean from an entity. Remove those auto wired fields from other classes. Trust me and @M.Deinum

Comment: You didn't have an empty `@Autowired` it was on the `addUser` method (despite the empty line). It doesn't make sense to make components out of entities, Spring doesn't need to detect those and Spring Data has other means to detect entities and repositories.